# Convert JSON object to JSON array with additional elements

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON object

```
{
    "https://www.google.com": "200",
    "https://www.facebook.com": "200",
    "https://www.yahoo.com": "401",
    "https://www.friendster.com": "404"
}
```

Is it possible to convert it to a JSON array with additional elements (url & status) in Javascript?

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://www.google.com",
    "status": "200"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.facebook.com",
    "status": "200"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.yahoo.com",
    "status": "401"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.friendster.com",
    "status": "404"
  }
 ]
```

Thank you for the tips.

Comment: **Yes**. Its possible. Only thing you need to write some code. Add some code which you have tried.

Comment: Iterate the Existing object and create a new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the string using `JSON.parse`, get all keys as an array and construct an array of objects with url and status properties

```
var json = '{\
    "https://www.google.com": "200",\
    "https://www.facebook.com": "200",\
    "https://www.yahoo.com": "401",\
    "https://www.friendster.com": "404"\
}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

var objWithUrlAndStatus = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
    return {
        url: key,
        status: obj[key]
    }
});

console.log(objWithUrlAndStatus);
```

Comment: Thank you. I am beginner. Can provide more info about Object.keys(obj).map(function (key)?

Comment: @snorlax `Object.keys` returns an array with content consisting of all (own, not inherited) enumerable properties (in your case all URLs, `["https://www.google.com", "https://www.facebook.com", ...]`). `map` is a method on array objects that lets you create a new array by mapping each value of source array to some other value. So, we map each URL in the source array to an object containing a `url` property which value is the URL and a `status` property which value we read from the parsed JSON under the URL-key.

Comment: @snorlax  Docs on [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: i see. is it also possible to do a filtering like only put the URLs with "200" into the new array?

Comment: Yes, no problem here. We can do the filtering  `Object.keys(obj).map(...).filter(function (obj) { return obj.status === "200"; });`. Alternative, to reduce the amount of steps, we can just use a basic `for..in` loop https://jsfiddle.net/3xjfyqmz/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery $.each

like this

```js
var data = {
    "https://www.google.com": "200",
    "https://www.facebook.com": "200",
    "https://www.yahoo.com": "401",
    "https://www.friendster.com": "404"
};
var finalData=[];
$.each(data,function(index,val){
  finalData.push({url:index,status:val});
});

console.log(finalData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```